# Соединить 2 двуммерных массива PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива:

Первый массив:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 24 
        [date] => 2014-06-03 15:45:48
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 25 
        [date] => 2014-06-05 16:21:25 
    )
)
```

Второй массив:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [date] => 2014-06-04 16:01:24
    )
)
```

Нужно сложить эти два массива и отсортировать, чтобы получилось так:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 24 
        [date] => 2014-06-03 15:45:48
    )
    [1] =>Array (
        [id] => 1
        [date] => 2014-06-04 16:01:24
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 25 
        [date] => 2014-06-05 16:21:25 
    )
)
```

Comment: сложить, затем отсортировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИМХО в данном случае уместнее (и удобнее) говорить не о двумерном массиве, а о массиве массивов.

[Операции с массивами](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php) или [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php). [Сортировка массивов](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php) (если требуется).

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_1 = [
    [
        'id' => 24,
        'date' => '2014-06-03 15:45:48'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 25,
        'date' => '2014-06-05 16:21:25'
    ],
];

$arr_2 = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'date' => '2014-06-04 16:01:24'
    ]
];

$array = array_merge($arr_1, $arr_2);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return (strtotime($a['date']) < strtotime($b['date'])) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($array);
```